# Selecting specific column for a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say I have a table called _table1 with column headers a, b, c, d, e.

I want a user defined function to do a calculation based on this table.

This is one example

```
Function TEST(var1 As Single, var2 As Single)
    TEST = Application.Index(range("_table1[c]"), var1 + var2)
End Function
```

This works, but because the _table1 is not defined in the input of the function, when the value of _table1 is changed, the function won't automatically change its value

I can do something like this

```
Function TEST(var1 As Single, var2 As Single, rng1 as Range)
    TEST = Application.Index(rng1.Columns(3), var1 + var2)
End Function
```

which will automatically change the value of the function when the value of the table changes.
But it will directly choose the third column of the table, not the one with header c. In the future I will need to change the arrangement of the column so it is more convenient to directly state the column to be the one with header c.

Is there any way the function will automatically change its value when the value of the table is changed and also let me choose which column?

Comment: If you want to specify the column then you can do `Function TEST(var1 As Single, var2 As Single, rng1 as Range, col as Long)`? and then `TEST = Application.Index(rng1.Columns(col), var1 + var2)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout that's not exactly what I want. What I want is so that the code will always use the column with the header c, even if in the future the column with the header c is no longer in the third column. But your solution is pretty interesting, perhaps I can make so that the variable col will always be the position of the header c

Comment: OR you can use `rng1.Find` to find the location of the column inside the function. I mean you have now 2 options. See which is easier for you :)